# Getting 404 for all compiled Angular files when serving from nginx + uwsgi using docker-compose

Tags: angular, nginx, flask, docker-compose, uwsgi

I am trying to create a web application using following technologies:

```
- Angular
- Flask
- Nginx
- uwsgi
- Docker
```

The problem is that I am getting 404 for all the compiled Angular Javascript files except index.html.

[image]

However, the route from Flask end is working fine as shown in below snapshot:

[image]

I tried few config changes in nginx.conf and docker files but in vain. I am new to Docker and not able to figure out as why the Angular application is failing to load. It would be great, If I could get some help on this.

> I have following code structure and it's contents:

`app/project/main/
  - static (Contains 'dist' dir that holds the output of ng build)
  - app.py
  - Dockerfile
  - requirements.txt
  - uwsgi.ini
nginx
  - nginx.conf
  - Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml`

> app.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/hello')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World from Flask using Python 2.7"
@app.route("/")
def main():
    return send_file('./static/dist/index.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

> Dockerfile (uwsgi)

```
FROM python:2.7

MAINTAINER Sanjiv Kumar

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ADD requirements.txt /usr/src/app/

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ADD . /usr/src/app

ADD uwsgi.ini /etc/uwsgi.ini

CMD uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi.ini
```

> Dockerfile (nginx)

```
FROM nginx:alpine

MAINTAINER Sanjiv Kumar

# Copy custom nginx config
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80 443

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx"]
CMD ["-g", "daemon off;"]
```

> requirements.txt

```
flask
uwsgi
```

> uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
http-socket = 0.0.0.0:8000
chdir = /usr/src/app/project/main
wsgi-file = app.py
callable = app
master = true
uid = 1
gid = 1
die-on-term = true
processes = 4
threads = 2
```

> docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '2.0'

services:

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx_container
    restart: always
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx/Dockerfile
    volumes_from:
      - app
    links:
      - "app"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - "app"

    networks:
      - app-network

  app:
    container_name: flask_container
    restart: always
    build: app
    volumes:
      - /usr/src/app/project
      - ./app/project/main/static/dist:/usr/src/app/project/main/static/dist
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

> nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes 1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
        ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 30m;

        #See http://blog.argteam.com/coding/hardening-node-js-for-production-part-2-using-nginx-to-avoid-node-js-load
        #proxy_cache_path        /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=one:8m max_size=3000m
        #inactive=600m;
        proxy_temp_path         /var/tmp;
        include                 mime.types;
        default_type            application/octet-stream;
        sendfile                on;
        keepalive_timeout       65;

        gzip                    on;
        gzip_comp_level         6;
        gzip_vary               on;
        gzip_min_length         1000;
        gzip_proxied            any;
        gzip_types              text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        gzip_buffers            16 8k;

    upstream flask {
       server app:8000;
    }

    server {
      listen       80;
      server_name  localhost;

      location /static {
          root   /usr/src/app/project/main/static;
          index  index.html;
          expires -1;
          add_header Pragma "no-cache";
          add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0,
          pre-check=0";
          try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
      }

      location / {
        #include    uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass flask;

        uwsgi_param Host $host;
        uwsgi_param X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
      }
    }


}
```

**Update**:

- Angular + Nginx + docker works fine but the issue is when I introduce Flask + uwsgi, I start getting 404s.
- I have tried changing few things in docker as well as nginx conf settings but still having the same issue. Also searched about similar issue but was not able to find one. It would be very helpful, if someone could guide me on this. Thanks.!

Comment: In the production build from where are you serving the static files like Js and css?what folder is that?

Comment: Under static, It's the 'dist' folder. Path:  `app/project/main/static/dist/`

Comment: Can you try accessing the JS files with a combination of these paths in the browser to better understand the problem. This seems to be static file serving issue.

Comment: I had tried accessing the js files but my guess is that they are somehow..not being copied/referenced..but If index.html is accessible then other js files too..not sure on this..I will try and let you know.

Comment: I am not able to locate js or css files on browser. I am guessing that the `index.html` file is being called from `app.py` and therefore that is located. However when the control is on Angular end, the app fails to load.

Comment: Guys..any input on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I almost forgot to post answer for my own question. Sorry for that.
So I figured out the issue, it was related to the way, I was accessing my angular and backend request using `nginx.conf`. I went through several blogs/github repos and got success at the end. I created a github repo with a working skeleton project and a read me to run the project locally. Please checkout here: [Angular-Flask-Docker-Skeleton](https://github.com/mrsan22/Angular-Flask-Docker-Skeleton)